# Press release distribution system Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: prior-art-request, online-advertising, us20130246165

This looks like a patent on all native advertising systems. Has anyone seen any prior art to this?

> Patent application title: PRESS RELEASE DISTRIBUTION SYSTEM Inventors:
>   Assignees:  NATIVO INC. IPC8 Class: USPC Class: 705 1445 Class name:
>   Publication date: 2013-09-19 Patent application number: [US20130246165](http://www.google.com/patents/us20130246165)
>
> Abstract: A press release distribution system provides press release
>   and other news to forum sites as posts. The forum software that runs
>   at forum sites includes press release interface software or is adapted
>   to receive press release interface plug-in modules for interfacing
>   with the press release distribution system. The press release
>   interface software or plug-in module may also monitor and/or analyze
>   user data of forum members and/or forum activities of the users. The
>   monitored user data and forum activities may be provided to the press
>   release distribution system for analysis and generation of user
>   profiles. Using the result of the analysis (e.g., user profiles), the
>   press release distribution system can target particular users or
>   forums to direct the press releases, news, or advertisements for most
>   effective advertising campaign.
>
> Claims:
>   1. A press release distribution system configured to deliver advertisements as sponsored news content to a plurality of web sites
>   that each includes non-sponsored content, the press release
>   distribution system comprising: a distributor module on a server
>   computer, the distributor module being adapted to distribute the
>   sponsored news content to a related one or more of the web sites over
>   a communications network; at least one input handler module on the
>   server computer, the at least one input handler module adapted to
>   receive the sponsored news content from one or more advertisers over
>   the communications network, and to provide the sponsored news content
>   to the distributor module; and at least one poster module adapted to
>   run at the related one or more of the web sites, wherein the at least
>   one poster module is adapted to receive the sponsored news content
>   from the server computer over the communications network, and to post
>   the sponsored news content among the non-sponsored content at each of
>   the related one or more of the web sites, wherein the at least one
>   poster module is further adapted to track one or more of impressions,
>   clicks, click-through rate, or user actions with respect to the
>   sponsored news content, and wherein the sponsored news content is not
>   a banner advertisement.
>
> 2. The press release distribution system of claim 1, wherein the sponsored news content comprises a press release, news, announcement,
>      message, news feed, or non-"press" event.
> 3. The press release distribution system of claim 1, wherein the non-sponsored content comprises one or more of messages, postings,
>      posts, or threads.
> 4. The press release distribution system of claim 1, wherein the communications network is the Internet.
> 5. The press release distribution system of claim 1, wherein the plurality of web sites comprise forum sites, fan sites, popular sites,
>      enthusiast sites, message forums, user forums, or popular forums.
> 6. The press release distribution system of claim 1, wherein the at least one poster module comprises a corresponding at least one press
>      release plug-in module.
> 7. The press release distribution system of claim 1, wherein the at least one poster module is further adapted to monitor user data or
>      user activity at the related one or more of the web sites.
> 8. The press release distribution system of claim 7, wherein the press release distribution system is further configured to generate user
>      profiles from the monitored user data or user activity at the related
>      one or more of the web sites.
> 9. The press release distribution system of claim 7, wherein the user activity at the related one or more of the web sites comprises one or
>      more of posts, reads of posts, or searches at the related one or more
>      of the web sites.
> 10. The press release distribution system of claim 1, wherein the sponsored news content comprises one or more of text, video, or
>       images.
> 11. A method of electronically delivering advertisements as sponsored news content to a plurality of web sites that each includes
>       non-sponsored content, the method comprising: electronically receiving
>       the sponsored news content by a server computer from one or more
>       advertisers over a communications network; electronically distributing
>       the sponsored news content by the server computer to a related one or
>       more of the web sites over the communications network; electronically
>       receiving the sponsored news content by the one or more web sites from
>       the server computer over the communications network; electronically
>       posting the sponsored news content among the non-sponsored content at
>       each of the related one or more of the web sites; and electronically
>       tracking one or more of impressions, clicks, click-through rate, or
>       user actions with respect to the sponsored news content at the related
>       one or more of the web sites, wherein the sponsored news content is
>       not a banner advertisement.
> 12. The method of claim 11, wherein the sponsored news content comprises a press release, news, announcement, message, news feed, or
>       non-"press" event.
> 13. The method of claim 11, wherein the non-sponsored content comprises one or more of messages, postings, posts, or threads.
> 14. The method of claim 11, wherein the communications network is the Internet.
> 15. The method of claim 11, wherein the plurality of web sites comprise forum sites, fan sites, popular sites, enthusiast sites,
>       message forums, user forums, or popular forums.
> 16. The method of claim 11 further comprising electronically monitoring user data or user activity at the related one or more of
>       the web sites.
> 17. The method of claim 16 further comprising electronically generating user profiles from the monitored user data or user activity
>       at the related one or more of the web sites.
> 18. The method of claim 16, wherein the user activity at the related one or more of the web sites comprises one or more of posts, reads of
>       posts, or searches at the related one or more of the web sites.
> 19. The method of claim 11, wherein the sponsored news content comprises one or more of text, video, or images. Description:
>       CROSS-REFERENCE TO RELATED APPLICATION
>
> [0001] This application is a continuation of application Ser. No.
>   11/772,014 filed Jun. 29, 2007, which claimed the benefit of U.S.
>   Provisional Application No. 60/817,771 filed Jun. 29, 2006, the entire
>   content of which is incorporated by reference herein.
>
> FIELD OF THE INVENTION
>
> [0002] The present invention relates to online brand marketing and
>   monitoring.
>
> Read more: http://www.faqs.org/patents/app/20130246165

Answer (score 1):

This patent is an implementation of [RCF3835](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3835) that at first appears specific to Press Releases, but then in claim 2 is broadened to any content.

Claims 3 to 5 just describe a webpage

Claim 6 is a description of a Data Provider in [RCF3835](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3835)

Claim 7 to 10 is the application of analytics to "Sponsored Content" Which Google has been using in Adwords since 2002, and other companies have been using much longer.

From claim 11 onward they are describing Google Adwords which first appeared in 2002

Answer (score 0):

I believe Wordpress (wordpress.com) does all the features described above.

If you replace "press release" with article or posting, it seems to me that wordpress covers all the items listed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an automated RSS feed poster meets a lot of these claims.

Here's one for SMF, dated January 2007: http://custom.simplemachines.org/mods/index.php?mod=624

Here's a similar one for WordPress from 2006: http://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/rss-widget/